# MSMQ asynchronous exception behavior - .NET 4.0 vs .NET 2.0

Tags: exception, asynchronous, .net-4.0, callback, msmq

I recently encountered a problem with asynchronous operations in MSMQ.  In .NET 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5, if there is a pending asynchronous receive, and the queue is deleted, the callback is invoked and upon calling EndReceive, the exception is thrown.

In .NET 4.0, the callback is never invoked, but the exception can be caught by the AppDomain.UnhandledException event handler.  When running in the debugger, the application will simply terminate with no notification from Visual Studio that an exception occurred.

This code is executing on Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit.  However the behavior is the same whether the application is targeting x86 or x64.  *(Edit:  verified this behavior on XP SP3 32-bit as well - this appears to be a framework bug, not OS-related)*

I am assuming this new behavior is related to .NET 4.0 being a completely new runtime.  I'm not sure what to do at this point, but essentially I am looking to get the pre-.NET 4.0 behavior back, while still targeting the .NET 4.0 runtime.  Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.  Here is sample code to reproduce the problem:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler( CurrentDomain_UnhandledException );
        string path = @".\private$\mytestqueue";
        // Create queue only if it doesn't already exist.
        var queue = MessageQueue.Exists( path ) ? new MessageQueue( path ) : MessageQueue.Create( path );
        queue.BeginReceive( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 15 ), queue, new AsyncCallback( ReceiveComplete ) );
        Thread.Sleep( 5000 );
        MessageQueue.Delete( path );
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException( object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e )
    {
        var mqEx = (MessageQueueException) e.ExceptionObject;

        // .NET 4.0:

        // "The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient
        // permissions to perform the operation."
        Console.WriteLine( mqEx.Message );
        // "QueueNotFound"
        Console.WriteLine( mqEx.MessageQueueErrorCode );
    }

    static void ReceiveComplete( IAsyncResult ar )
    {
        // This callback is never invoked under .NET 4.0.
        Console.WriteLine( "Finishing Receive." );
        var queue = (MessageQueue) ar.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            queue.EndReceive( ar );
        }
        catch ( MessageQueueException mqEx )
        {
            // .NET 2.0 through 3.5:

            // "Queue handle can no longer be used to receive messages
            // because the queue was deleted. The handle should be closed."
            Console.WriteLine( mqEx.Message );
            // "QueueDeleted"
            Console.WriteLine( mqEx.MessageQueueErrorCode );
        }
    }
}
```

*Addendum:*

After spending way too much time trying to use source stepping (System.Messaging source is available for 4.0 but not for 2.0/3.5, it appears), and hunting through the two different System.Messaging assemblies with Reflector, I finally found the problem.

In the 2.0 assembly, some try/catch blocks are used in the MessageQueue.AsynchronousRequest.RaiseCompletionEvent method to catch exceptions and store an error code so that the exception can be raised when .EndReceive() is called.  However, in the 4.0 assembly, these try/catches are gone, so when an exception occurs the process must terminate since they are un-caught on a background thread.

Unfortunately this doesn't help me fix the problem.  I am considering switching to a synchronous Receive, but I liked the idea of taking advantage of I/O completion ports for this.

Comment: You convinced me, post this to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @Hans:  Great idea, I should have thought of that before!  For anyone who runs across this question and has the same issue, here is the bug on Connect:  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/626177/messagequeue-beginreceive-asynchronous-exception-behavior

Comment: Now I just get a "Page not found" when navigating to the microsoft connect site. Anyone have any information on the status of this bug?

Comment: Coincidentally, I looked up this question a couple days ago to check it out on Connect and saw that too.  I am running .NET 4.5.2 on my machine now and my above test code works properly no matter which framework version is targeted; additionally, if I use ILSpy I see the same code in the RaiseCompletionEvent method for both the 2.0 and 4.0 versions of System.Messaging.dll.  So it appears to have been fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I am going to answer this and accept it, since I think it's the best answer for the near future.  It could be months (or more) before there is a proper solution.

As mentioned above, I filed a bug report on Microsoft Connect, so it is pretty much up to them to revert the behavior to how it worked in CLR 2.0.

Microsoft Connect:  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/626177/messagequeue-beginreceive-asynchronous-exception-behavior

As far as how this affects my application, I am not willing to switch to a synchronous Receive method, as that would consume all of the available worker threads on the thread pool.  My application frequently creates and removes a lot of queues, and this issue arose when a command to remove a queue was issued, but an outstanding read operation was pending.  Instead, I will just mark that a queue needs to be removed, and once a safe period of time has elapsed (two times the BeginReceive timeout, for instance), I will actually remove the queue.

Or switch to a different queuing system than MSMQ, though I've been happy with it so far.

Comment: ... **frequently** create and remove **a** **lot** of queues? Why?